# How does a 32-bit DSP address 2³² values without enough RAM?

Tags: computer-architecture

A 32-bit CPU in a PC is capable of addressing 2³² individual bytes. How do DSPs and microprocessors handle such a large address space when they have RAMs only in MBs at the most?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please note that it's not a free personal tutorial, homework-answering service or on-line technical encyclopedia, copied out to you on demand. People will help you take the next step if your question shows you've done as much as you possibly could on your own - which yours doesn't, I'm afraid. Please edit your question and greatly improve it. Show your work and own findings so far in considerable detail. The better the quality of question, the better the quality of the answers you will attract. Again, a very warm welcome.

Comment: 2^32 bytes is 4 Gigabytes

Comment: Please clarify your question. I don't see the connection between a CPUs addressing and a microprocessors in your question.

Comment: Is your question perhaps "why do the processors have such a large address space when their internal memory is small"? Then the answer is - that it can be extended by connecting external memories and/or memory-mapped peripherals.

Comment: .. or to implement arbitrarily much virtual memory addresses, which can be very handy in the context of DSP.

Comment: The theoretical ability to address a large memory does not mean that there has to actually be anything at those locations.  In most cases apart from maxed-out 32-bit desktop PC's, the address space is not fully populated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your question is based on two incorrect assumptions.

- A 32-bit CPU is capable of addressing 2³² individual bytes, so it must include 2³² bytes of RAM.

Merely being able to address 2³² individual bytes does not require actually having 2³² bytes of RAM. To have address space of 2³², the CPU only needs to use 1 number (i.e. a 32-bit integer) to represent its memory address, one address at a time, not 2³² numbers simultaneously.

Also, a memory address don't necessarily map to an uniquely usable physical memory cell. It's perfectly possible to have a 32-bit computer with only 128 MiB of RAM installed. The remaining address space in this case can simply be unused. And in fact, a larger-than-physical-memory address space is still beneficial since it can be utilized to implement [Memory-Mapped I/O](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory-mapped_I/O) and [virtual memory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory), which use parts of the address space to represent something other than "real" physical memory.

- An n-bit CPU must have an n-bit address space, and must support n-bit of physical RAM.

Usually, we assume a modern n-bit CPU that support n-bit integer arithmetic operations has an n-bit address space and support n-bit of physical RAM. But it isn't always the case. The Motorola 68000 is an interesting example - it supports 32-bit arithmetic operations, has a 32-bit address space, but only include a 24-bit physical address bus, and a 16-bit data bus. Is it a 16-bit CPU, a 24-bit CPU or a 32-bit CPU? It's thought to be 32-bit due to its capability of doing 32-bit arithmetic, and also considered to be 16-bit due to its data bus width. But both answers would be wrong if you expect the "n-bit" indicates the amount of physical memory supported by the CPU, which is 2²⁴ bytes. Going back further, many historical CPUs, such as the Intel 8080, support 2¹⁶ bytes of physical memory despite being 8-bit CPUs.

Thus, being considered as an n-bit CPU does not require actually having 2^n bytes of RAM, also, the "n-bit" does not even always imply the amount of physical memory supported by the CPU.

Comment: x86 is another good example.  In 32 bit mode physical addressing is 36 bits.  In 64 bit mode, current Xeons (Skylake-SP) use 46 bit physical memory addressing.

Comment: @user1850479 The 48-bit addressing in 64-bit CPUs was also what I had in my mind, but I decided to use a simpler example, because the actual physical memory supported on a PC is limited to an even lower size (sometimes even artificially) by the integrated DRAM controller in CPUs, which adds to the confusion.